# Compare the Current And Next Element of A set

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I want to compare the current and next element of a set of addresses  . I tried the following code

```
    struct Address{
          string state;
          string city;
    }

    if((*it).state == (*(it+1)).state){
    }
```

But the compiler gave an error that no match for operator+ in "it+1". On [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/) I found that + operator is not supported for set containers. So I am unable to figure out a way to access both the current and the next element of a set in the same if statement.

Comment: `std::set` contain unique elements. Performing an equality check will always return false.

Comment: @hmjd: not necessarily, since only a part of the object is compared and we don't know how the object comparison is implemented.

Comment: @Grizzly, true. Just noticed the equality is on `state` only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But `++` is provided, so you can write:

```
?::iterator next = it;
next++;
```

Comment: +1. And don't forget to ensure that `next != end` before trying to dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a copy of the iterator, advance it(++), then compare.  Or, if your standard library has it, you can use the c++11 `next` function from the `<iterator>` library.

```
if(it->state == std::next(it)->state)
```

Comment: +1 for `next`: it fills a much-needed gap left behind by `advance`.

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out the operator `+` is not supported for `std::set` iterators, since those are only `bidirectional iterators` and not `random access iterators`. So if you want to access the next element at the same time as the current one you have to make a copy and increment that one:

```
std::set<Address>::iterator next_it = it;
++next_it;
if(it->state == (next_it)->state)
```

If you are using c++11 this code can be simplyfied using the `std::next` function found in `<iterator>`(which basically does the same thing):

```
if(it->state == std::next(it)->state)
```

Of course writing that function is pretty trivial, so you could always write your own `next` when coding pre C++11 .

Also: Remember to make sure that the next iterator isn't equal to `set.end()`